# NodeMCU/ESP8266 secure post to Azure IoT

Tags: azure, ssl, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to implement a basic sensor-to-cloud system sending data from an ESP8266 microcontroller to Azure IoT cloud via RESTful HTTP/HTTPS POSTs.

The NodeMCU Lua interpreter is used.

I've omitted the code here for brevity that actually reads the sensors and connects to the WiFi LAN. These work correctly.

I've got this working successfully with HTTP POSTs to UbiDots, but I can't get Azure to work - I think the enforced HTTPS is the part I can't get working.

I've generated a SAS token, set up the Azure IoT Hub, and I'm pretty sure the HTTP header is right and the authorization line is included with the SAS which I've generated from Azure's IOT hub explorer tool.

=== EDITS ===

```
My NodeMCU build is as follows:
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
                branch: dev
                commit: 5e1ca234cce36f251edd78dc3d5a5ce4d4c76a59
                SSL: true
                modules: adc,crypto,ds18b20,file,gpio,http,hx711,net,node,ow,sntp,tmr,uart,wifi,tls
 build created on 2018-04-26 07:02
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(cfd48f3)
```

I've now made everything much neater with a refactor using NodeMCU HTTP(S) library. Relevant code as follows:

```
function postHTTPWebService(name1, val1, name2, val2, name3, val3, name4, val4)

  tls.cert.verify([[
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-- certificate mostly redacted
  MIIFtDCCBJygAwIBAgIQCLh6UBu+nNotFk0+OVG/VTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBa
  86Qho5jQenT2jOjD0iuqK84RWRlE51wHCULr1/0VTblvbEQ1Joe6oztosIHnIMl/
  EwLzzKufHJVQy65kgLuHCl3OpmuyfeM9NuIpUbcl/NAJ47CtxGIuPn6FJrL2r/dt
  N2UI+5Gz6BZ2YSpl9ViUs0UB78BPA3u4
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  ]])

  tls.cert.verify(true)

  azure_url =
    "https://" .. AZURE_HUB .. ".azure-devices.net/devices/" ..
    AZURE_DEVICE .. "/messages/events?api-version=" .. AZURE_API

  azure_payload = json(name1, val1, name2, val2, name3, val3, name4, val4)

  azure_headers =
    "Authorization: " .. SAS_TOKEN .. "\r\n" ..
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" ..
    "Content-Length: " .. string.len(azure_payload) .. "\r\n" ..
    "Host: " .. AZURE_HUB .. ".azure-devices.net\r\n\n"

  http.post(azure_url, azure_headers, azure_payload,
    function(return_status, return_payload)
    if (return_status < 0) then -- big fail, no HTTP return at all
      print("HTTP request failed")
    elseif (return_status == 200) then
      print(return_payload)
      print("Got HTTP 200 return - entering deep sleep")
      node.dsleep(DEEPSLEEP_TIME)
    else
      -- There are many HTTP codes which are valid but still unsuccessful
      print("Got valid return status - not 200")
      print(return_status, return_payload)
    end
  end)
end
```

When I use `tls.cert.verify(true)` I get the following output:

```
E:M 1472
E:M 1520
E:M 1520
HTTP client: Disconnected with error: 88
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP request failed
```

Now let's try `tls.cert.verify(false)`

```
E:M 40
E:M 1520
E:M 1520
E:M 120
HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -123
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP request failed
```

And try `tls.cert.verify(false)` again:

```
E:M 264
E:M 1520
E:M 1520
HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -16
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP request failed
```

=== END EDITS ===

I do get that the HTTP library would make the code a bit neater, but at the moment I've already written the code without using it, and I haven't gone back and edited it yet to use the HTTP lib etc. It should still work using the general socket library, I think, and *does* still work for an unsecured plain HTTP post, so I'd like to get something working right now with minimal changes.

The following is the faulty part I think

```
  serv_addr = AZURE_HUB .. ".azure-devices.net"
  tls.cert.verify(true)
  connection:connect(443, serv_addr)
end
```

Is this the correct server address structure, correct port and correct tls use, and correct cert.verify() ?

A minimum working example for successful communication to Azure might be really nice if anybody knows where to find one for NodeMCU. I haven't found one yet.

It's a bit of a headache for me at the moment, but I suppose it's good that they're pretty much forcing a transition to relatively secure end-to-end systems for IoT edge node devices.

I've previously generated the certificate :

```
tls.cert.verify([[
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
foo blah blah blah here is the certificate generated
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
]])

tls.cert.verify(true)
```

So now when my code calls tls.cert.verify(true) this certificate should already be stored in flash.

```
AZURE_DEVICE = "MyAzureDeviceName"
AZURE_HUB = "myazureiothub"
AZURE_API = "2016-02-03"

SAS_TOKEN = "123AFthisisafaketokenC4%3D"
DEEPSLEEP_TIME = 60000000 -- 1 minute in microseconds

local module = {}

function format_json(variable1, value1, variable2, value2, variable3, value3, variable4, value4)
  payload =
            '{\"' .. variable1..'\": {"value": ' .. value1..'},\"'
            .. variable2 .. '\": {"value": ' .. value2 .. '},\"'
            .. variable3 .. '\": {"value": ' .. value3 .. '},\"'
            .. variable4 .. '\": {"value": ' .. value4 .. '}}'
  return payload
end

function postHTTPWebService(name1, value1, name2, value2, name3, value3, name4, value4)

  connection =  tls.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
  connection:on("receive", function(connection, payload)
    if (string.find(payload, "200 OK") ~= nil) then
      print("HTTP 200 received - OK");
      connection:close();
      collectgarbage();
      node.dsleep(DEEPSLEEP_TIME)
    else
      print("HTTP Return Error")
      print(payload) -- print the HTTP status returned. 
    end
  end)

  connection:on("connection", function(connection, payload)
    data = format_json(name1, value1, name2, value2, name3, value3, name4, value4)
    local post = "POST /devices/" .. AZURE_HUB .. "/messages/events?api-version=" .. AZURE_API .. " HTTP/1.1\r\n" ..
    "Host: " .. AZURE_HUB .. ".azure-devices.net\r\n" ..
    "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature " .. SAS_TOKEN .. "\r\n" ..
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" ..
    "Content-Length: " .. string.len(data) .. "\r\n" ..
    "\r\n" .. data .. "\n"
    print(post) -- print the full HTTP payload for debugging
    connection:send(post)
    print("HTTP POST sent.")
    end)

  connection:on("disconnection", function(connection, payload)
    connection:close();
    collectgarbage();
  end)

  serv_addr = AZURE_HUB .. ".azure-devices.net"
  tls.cert.verify(true)
  connection:connect(443, serv_addr)
end

function readSensors()
  value1 = 1 -- Dummy sensor data for testing
  value2 = 2
  value3 = 3
  value4 = 4
  postHTTPWebService("sensor1", value1, "sensor2", value2, "sensor3", value3, "sensor4", value4)
end

local function main_function()

  -- Wait a second, then run the sensor function
  tmr.alarm(3, 1000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function() readSensors() end)
end

function module.start()
  main_function()
end
return module
```

Comment: What happens if you switch cert.verify to false? For the verify to succeed your device needs to have the Root CA that signed the *.azure-devices.net cert. There's usually a helper binary that flashes multiple root CAs onto the device flash, at least that's the case for ATWINC1500, no idea about ESP.

Comment: It could be there's no common cipher suite with the remote. You can run the remote through ssllabs.com and compare. Not sure how to get the supported ciphers for your device though.. One way is run a simple openssl s_server in www mode and see what gets advertised in the handshake.

Comment: I can just run openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myiothub.azure-devices.net:8883 on my PC, right? Is this the correct way to get the certificate?

Comment: Yes. Should be the first one served, the one issued by Baltimore Cybertrust Root.

Comment: I've tried both certificates, (CN = Baltimore CyberTrust Root is the second one on the list?) and it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Yeah I don't even think it gets to cert verification, the handshake breaks way earlier (no common ciphers?) You could proxy through an Azure Function, they can do plain HTTP.